# angular thousand separator for all numbers throughout project

Tags: angular, html, number-formatting, separator

I am using Angular 6 and HTML 5 to create a responsive web page.

I want to format all variables with type "number" so that all numbers getting displayed will have thousand separators.

This is how I implement a thousand separator on every number:

```
const num = value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ' ');
```

Is there a way that I can only specify this format once, and it can automatically be used for every "number" format variable, instead of specifying it at every variable I display?

Comment: do you want to only show the numbers with thousand seperators or you also want to change the model?

Comment: You can format numbers by using Angular pipes. I think it will work but if you want to define different functionality then you can use custom pipes https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular built-in [Decimal pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)

You can also write a custom pipe like this:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform }     from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'seprator'})
export class Seprator implements PipeTransform {
  
  constructor() {

  }

  transform(value: string, unit: string): string {

    if(value == undefined)
    {
        return '';
    }
    let n = parseInt(value);

    const rx =  /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    return String(n).replace(/^\d+/, function (w) {
        var res = w;
        while (rx.test(res)) {
            res = res.replace(rx, '$1٬$2');
        }
        return res;
    });

  }
}
```